# Timing Changes With JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I wish to execute different functions at different times without them overlapping with each other.

Bit of context - I want to remove elements of a page one element at a time rather than all at once over a period of time.

For example, at 1:00am remove element 1 then at 2:00am remove element 1 + 2 and so on.

The removal of the elements will be done using JQuery.

**EDIT:**

```
    window.setInterval(function(){ // Set interval for checking
    var date = new Date(); // Create a Date object to find out what time it is
    if(date.getHours() === 12 && date.getMinutes() === 18){ // Check the time
        $(function() {
    //Remove Elements
    $('#element1').remove();
       })
}, 10000); // Repeat every 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds)
```

This is what I have so far for timing one function - seeing error : **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,** .

Comment: I wish to see the code you have written so far, and where you need help..?

Comment: Supposedly you've tried something here. If you didn't, please start with thinking about a solution (or a direction to a solution) yourself, then share your thoughts here. The SO-community is not inclined to write the code for you.

Comment: Added what I have so far - I'm asking as I don't know how to add timings to a function to be executed.

Comment: @sclarke: try searching on `setTimeout` (withinin SO or the web)

Comment: You are missing a `}` for closing the if function

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code snippet that has two variants for scheduled removal of elements.

- option 1: specify `after` in milliseconds and it will remove element by given selector after milliseconds pass. Timeout starts to count after calling `ScheduledRemover.work(settings);`
- option 2: specify `at` as object which could have the following structure

__

```
at: {
    h: 14, // (Optional) the hour at which remove should be executed
    m: 30, // (Optional) the minute at which remove should be executed
    s: 23  // (Optional) the second at which remove should be executed
}
```

The code will calculate the difference of current time and desired removal time and will set timeout using `setTimeout` to execute the removal. This way you don't have to check every time in `setInterval` if the time has come.

Hope this was helpful. Let me know if any questions come up. Cheers!

```js
var ScheduledRemover = (function() {

  function _work(settings) {
    for (let i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {
      let schedulerRemove = settings[i];
      if (schedulerRemove.at) {
        /* Remove element at specific time */
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var removalTime = new Date();
        if (typeof schedulerRemove.at.h === 'number') {
          removalTime.setHours(schedulerRemove.at.h);
        }
        if (typeof schedulerRemove.at.m === 'number') {
          removalTime.setMinutes(schedulerRemove.at.m);
        }
        if (typeof schedulerRemove.at.s === 'number') {
          removalTime.setSeconds(schedulerRemove.at.s);
        }

        var removeAfter = removalTime - currentTime;
        if (removeAfter >= 0) {
          /* If difference is less than 0 then time for the removal passed */
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(schedulerRemove.selector).remove();
            console.log(schedulerRemove.selector + ' removed ...');
          }, removeAfter);
        } else {
          console.log('Time passed for removing ' + schedulerRemove.selector);
        }
      } else if (schedulerRemove.after) {
        /* Remove element after specific time */
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(schedulerRemove.selector).remove();
          console.log(schedulerRemove.selector + ' removed ...');
        }, schedulerRemove.after);
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    work: _work
  }
}());

var settings = [{
    selector: '#element1',
    after: 2000
  },
  {
    selector: '#element2',
    after: 5000
  },
  {
    selector: '#element3',
    at: {
      h: 14,
      m: 49
    }
  },
  {
    selector: '#element4',
    at: {
      h: 14,
      m: 53,
      s: 1
    }
  },
  {
    selector: '#element5',
    after: 30000
  }
];

ScheduledRemover.work(settings);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element1">Element 1</div>
<div id="element2">Element 2</div>
<div id="element3">Element 3</div>
<div id="element4">Element 4</div>
<div id="element5">Element 5</div>
```